# How to run a C++ program in another C++ program?

Tags: c++, linux

I have a simple C++ program that takes in inputs and outputs some string. Like this:

```
$ ./game
$ what kind of game? type r for regular, s for special.
$ r
$ choose a number from 1 - 10
$ 1
$ no try again
$ 2
$ no try again
$ 5
$ yes you WIN!
```

Now I want to write a c++ program can runs this c++ program and plays the game automatically without user input and then outputs it to a file or standard output.

Running it would look like this:

```
./program game r > outputfile
```

game is the game program, r for playing regular style.

How should I do this? The main reason I need this program is that I want to do automatic testing for a much bigger program.

Comment: Most of the times for testing other languages are used, like python or tcl. Which provide you with some easier methods to do this (you should search for expect).

Comment: @killianDS: hmm I haven't used Python before, do you have a good example how to do this?

Answer (score 6):

You could use `std::system` from `<cstdlib>`:

```
std::system("game r > outputfile");
```

The return value is `./program`'s, the sole argument must be of type `char const *`.

There is no standard way to run a program and feed it standard input, though. Judging by your command line, you're on some Unix variant where `popen` from `<stdio.h>` should work:

```
FILE *sub = popen("game r > outputfile", "w");
```

then write to `sub` with the `stdio` functions and read `outputfile` afterwards.

(But for simple testing, I'd recommend implementing the core logic of your program as a set of functions/classes that can be run by a custom main function in a loop; or pick your favorite scripting language to handle this kind of thing.)

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand this answer, could you explain how this runs game and do automatic input?

Comment: @Mark: you're asking something that is actually quite complicated. Proper testing in C++ requires either knowledge of the platform you're on, or a framework that implements such knowledge. See updated answer.

Comment: I don't understand why you have "./program game r > outputfile" in system and popen. I haven't even implemented ./program yet.

Comment: @Mark: ah, that's what `./program` is. Just `game`, then.

Comment: @Could you adjust your answer to reflect this? Because I still don't understand what to do next. Also, do you know if this kind of test is easy on python?

Comment: Done. And yes, in Python this is doable, but the fact that your program does interactive I/O poses a challenge. Check out `pexpect`, or, again, refactor it so you can write custom `main` functions for testing.

Answer (score 1):

This scenario cries out for a "script", IMHO.

Bash, Perl, Python - you name it.

SIMPLEST CASE:

Just write a bash script to call `./program game r > outputfile`.

Or `./program game r < test_input.txt > test_output.txt`

For more advanced scenarios, you might want to look at "[expect](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3065)".

You might also want to look at "STAF", which might be a great way to "automate your automated tests":

http://staf.sourceforge.net/current/STAFFAQ.htm

Answer (score 1):

I'd be more efficient to add a caller function to your main source and have it control looping, logging, and feeding input.  It would also not require system calls or other magic to pull off.  Being a game programmer, we have our games play themselves as much as possible to help with debugging, and almost always this is done via internal code, not through external scripting or system calls.  It makes it easier to feed viable input as well.

Comment: The person I am working with is reluctant to let me change his code. This is my only plan.

Comment: Then have him make an interface for allowing input, such that you don't need to change his code and then you cna call his functions in your own code.  That'd be the way I would do it.  BTW, why is he so relectent for help?