# Using python to run a C++ program and test it

Tags: c++, python

Suppose I have a simple C++ program that takes in inputs and outputs some string. Like this (actual program is much more complicated but still text based):

```
$ ./game
$ what kind of game? type r for regular, s for special.
$ r
$ choose a number from 1 - 10
$ 1
$ no try again
$ 2
$ no try again
$ 5
$ yes you WIN!
```

I haven't used Python before, but is it possible to write a python script to run this program, feeds it input, and outputs the results to standard output? I have ask the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783256/run-c-program-in-c-program) about running it using C++ but it seems much too complicated. It would be awesome it you could direct me to some code examples. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might also want to consider `expect` (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [pexpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect).

Normal stdin/stdout piping usually doesn't work, because the standard library facilities in the parent and child processes tend to buffer I/O more aggressively when a file descriptor isn't a TTY (via the `isatty` call). Obviously, you can fix this in the parent, since you own that code; just call flush at appropriate points. But often the child process is running some preexisting code that you don't own. The pexpect module feeds the child process a pseudo-tty, which tricks the child into thinking it's talking to a console. This is the same trick that GUI terminals like xterm and rxvt use.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in [Cram](https://bitheap.org/cram/), which is a Python tool for testing command line options.

Answer (score 0):

If you're up to it you can use my testing framework which includes a Python version of `expect`. The original `expect` program allows you to "converse" with interactive programs just like that. But this framework includes a Python expect.py module that you can use instead.

See http://code.google.com/p/pycopia/

The module is in the process subpackage.

You could also use pexpect, but I wrote my own because I didn't like that one.